# How do I show DIV when click again in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made 4 boxes that are all hidden, and it shows only div(HOME) when page load.

When click the text "box2", hide other DIVs and show box2(DIV) and click box3 hide other DIVs and show box3(DIV).......

The question is while box2 is shown and click text box2 again, how do i show the first one box(home) ? I mean when click the menu again, how to show to home DIV?

Here is Demo 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/3qepfzvn/11/

Here is my code

```
<div class="m1"><a href="#" class="s1">HOME</a><a href="#" class="s2">box2</a><a href="#" class="s3">box3</a><a href="#" class="s4">box4</a></div>

<div class="m2"><a href="#" class="s1">HOME</a><a href="#" class="s2">box2</a><a href="#" class="s3">box3</a><a href="#" class="s4">box4</a></div>

<div class="m3"><a href="#" class="s1">HOME</a><a href="#" class="s2">box2</a><a href="#" class="s3">box3</a><a href="#" class="s4">box4</a></div>

<div class="m4"><a href="#" class="s1">HOME</a><a href="#" class="s2">box2</a><a href="#" class="s3">box3</a><a href="#" class="s4">box4</a></div>



jQuery(function(){
    $(".m1").show();
    $(".m2").hide();
    $(".m3").hide();
    $(".m4").hide();

    $(".s1").click(function(){ 
        $(".m1").show();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 

    });
    $(".s2").click(function(){
        $(".m1").hide();
        $(".m2").slideDown();
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 

    });
    $(".s3").click(function(){
        $(".m1").hide();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").slideDown();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 

    });
    $(".s4").click(function(){
        $(".m1").hide();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").slideDown();
        $(".s1").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").addClass("bold"); 

    });

});


a { color:black; margin:0 5px;}
.m1 {  background:gray; width:400px; height:100px; }
.m2 { background:blue; width:400px; height:400px; }
.m3 { background:yellow; width:400px; height:300px; }
.m4 { background:green; width:400px; height:600px; }

.bold { font-weight:bold; }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want?

Comment: code from my nightmare

Comment: Would you not be better using jQuery ui tabs?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
jQuery(function(){
$(".m1").show();
$(".m2").hide();
$(".m3").hide();
$(".m4").hide();

var m1Status = true;
var m2Status = false;
var m3Status = false;
var m4Status = false;


$(".s1").click(function(){ 
    $(".m1").show();
    $(".m2").hide();
    $(".m3").hide();
    $(".m4").hide();
    $(".s1").addClass("bold"); 
    $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
    $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
    $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 
     m1Status = true;
     m2Status = false;
     m3Status = false;
     m4Status = false;

});
$(".s2").click(function(){
    if (!m2Status){
        $(".m1").hide();
        $(".m2").slideDown();
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 
        m1Status = false;
        m2Status = true;
        m3Status = false;
        m4Status = false;
    }else{
        $(".m1").show();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 
        m1Status = true;
        m2Status = false;
        m3Status = false;
        m4Status = false;
    }
});
$(".s3").click(function(){
  if (!m3Status){
        $(".m1").hide();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").slideDown();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 
        m1Status = false;
        m2Status = false;
        m3Status = true;
        m4Status = false;
    }else{
        $(".m1").show();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 
        m1Status = true;
        m2Status = false;
        m3Status = false;
        m4Status = false;
    }

});
$(".s4").click(function(){
   if (!m4Status){
        $(".m1").hide();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").slideDown();
        $(".s1").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").addClass("bold"); 
        m1Status = false;
        m2Status = false;
        m3Status = false;
        m4Status = true;
    }else{
        $(".m1").show();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 
        m1Status = true;
        m2Status = false;
        m3Status = false;
        m4Status = false;
    } 

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With toggle you can make it work

**html**

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>
     <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding:           5px; width: 150px;">
        <a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" >show this one only</a>
     </div>
     <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: block;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #1</div>
  </td>
  <td>
     <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
        <a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >show this one only</a>
     </div>
     <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #2</div>
  </td>
  <td>
     <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
        <a id="myHeader3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" >show this one only</a>
     </div>
     <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #3</div>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**jquery**

```
With this code you can hide when you click box2 or box3.   

function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).show(200);
      }
      else {
           $(this).hide(600);
      }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function(){
    $(".m1").show();
    $(".m2").hide();
    $(".m3").hide();
    $(".m4").hide();
    var homeshow = false;

    $(".s1").click(function(){ 
        $(".m1").show();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 

    });
    $(".s2").click(function(){
        if(homeshow){
        homeshow = !homeshow;
        $(".m1").hide();
        $(".m2").slideDown();
        }else{
         homeshow = !homeshow;
         $(".m2").hide();
         $(".m1").slide();
        }
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 

    });
    $(".s3").click(function(){
        $(".m1").hide();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").slideDown();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 

    });
    $(".s4").click(function(){
        $(".m1").hide();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").slideDown();
        $(".s1").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").addClass("bold"); 

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation, and/or make this a bit more concise?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var activeDiv = 1;
jQuery(function(){
    $(".m1").show();
    $(".m2").hide();
    $(".m3").hide();
    $(".m4").hide();

    $(".s1").click(function(){
        activeDiv = 1; 
        $(".m1").show();
        $(".m2").hide();
        $(".m3").hide();
        $(".m4").hide();
        $(".s1").addClass("bold"); 
        $(".s2").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s3").removeClass("bold"); 
        $(".s4").removeClass("bold"); 

    });
    $(".s2").click(function(){
      if(activeDiv==2)
        {
            activeDiv = 1;
            $(".m1").show();
            $(".m2").hide();
        }  
      else
        {
          activeDiv = 2;
          $(".m1").hide();
          $(".m2").slideDown();
          $(".m3").hide();
          $(".m4").hide();
        }
      ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `.siblings()` and `.index()` for this, and if you're keeping the same pattern it can be done with a single function call -

```
$("div>a").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        index = $this.index(); // first is 0, second is 1 etc

    $("body>div").eq(index).show() // Change to find the correct divs
        .siblings("div").hide();
    $(".s" + (index + 1)).addClass("bold")
        .siblings("a").removeClass("bold");
});
```